# SQL Server 2012 average several columns with unknown rows and convert NULL to zero

Tags: sql, null, sql-server-2012, average, zero

I am trying to get the average of several columns and group by name. I need to include NULL and count as zero. Every way I have tried, I get the wrong number. I am also joining several tables to create the theoretical table below

```
location  first_name   last_name    col1  
-----------------------------------------
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     NULL    
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     NULL   
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     17  
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     21
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     21
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     47
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     60
x         f.name_1     l.name_1     65
```

Query:

```
select
     m.location
     p.first_name
     p.last_name
     avg(cast(ISNULL(l.col1,0) as float))
from
    table l as l
inner join
    table m as m on...
inner join
    table p as p on....
group by
    m.location, p.first_name, p.last_name
order by
    m.location, p.last_name
```

When I run this query, I am getting 2.20918... when I really want 28.5

Comment: Your joins are multiplying the number of rows, which affects the average.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that? My report would be meaningless without that information

Comment: .20918 is an unusual fraction. Try also returning `count(isnull(l.col1, 0))` to see what the divisor was.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete query (`on...` isn't much help) and the data that's in all the tables which produced the "theoretical table" you show. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, the average of those numbers you show including zeroes for null is 25.6667.

Comment: @Linday . . . You should probably delete this question (it has no answers).  Then ask another answer with more details, such as sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please provide relevant schema of tables L, M and P and how you join those.

Comment: @shawnt00: Values in the resulting table have average per row and not average of the whole table, so those numbers are irrelevant to calculate anything from. As you can see from query OP is grouping by location and person and then displaying average of each such group (average per person per location). `col1` values in result table should therefore actually be the calculated `avg` of each individual group.

Comment: @Robert I recognize the grouping and I took the sample as likely to be intended as representative of one such group. My point is that the only way to end up with that fraction is with more rows and hopefully point OP to look closer at the data.

Comment: @shawnt00 I was only commenting on your calculated average where you're saying it's 25.6667. That's what my comment was about. Your first comment though is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have something like this in your L table:

```
create table L (
    Id int not null
        identity
        primary key,
    LocationID int not null
        references M(Id),
    PersonId int not null
        references P(Id),
    Value float null,
    ...
)
```

There may be other columns as well, but the important thing is that your primary key on the table is not set to **Location+Person** because in such case there would be nothing to average as each person per location would only have one single row.

### Possible problem - duplicate locations/persons

All your joins are actually inner ones, which means that each row in your L table should map to a single row, when your join M and P tables to it. The only problem I see is if there would be ambiguous records for the Location+Person combination since you're not grouping by IDs but rather by strings. And you may have something like:

```
Table M:
ID   Name
---------------
1    Here
2    There
3    Everywhere
4    Here
```

This means that all records that belong to location 1 and 4 will be grouped together as you're not grouping by ID. The same would be true for table P. It's easy to see that there may be two John Smiths in table P each with a different ID. **Grouping should be by ID not by strings.**

> Note: If/when you provide additional info in your question we'll be able to better troubleshoot your problem of invalid averages but until then this is the most I can write for now.